In the Critique of Judgment, why does Kant insist that teleological judgment is a form of reflecting judgment?
I'm just starting the critique of judgment, so I don't have a lot to cite for this question, just the published introduction of 1790, about 25 pages long, and the one that he chose not to publish, the 50 pager, which didn't get fully published until 1914 (although excerpts of it were going around even during Kant's lifetime).
In that critique, Kant separates determining judgment from reflective judgment, where determining judgment corresponds to theoretical reasoning and reflecting judgment to aesthetic and teleological reasoning.
My question is wouldn't it have been better had Kant created a different structure?  if instead of combining the aesthetic and teleological under reflecting, he had made teleological its own separate category?  Had he done that, we would have a nice structure that pairs determining judgment to theoretical reasoning, reflecting judgment to aesthetics, and teleogical judgments to practical reason or ethics.
Those seem like good fits and I cannot see, at least so far in my reading, what the problem would be with doing that.  In other words, if the faculties are separated (Critiques 1, 2, and 3), why not do the same with the judgments?

Because "Judgment in its determining role subsumes given particulars under concepts or universals which are themselves already given... The more distinctive role assigned to judgment in the Critique of Judgment is the reflecting role, that of “finding” the universal for the given particular", see SEP. Aesthetics and teleology both deal with 'values' and do not separate at this level of abstraction.

Thank you for commenting, Connifold, but as there's clearly a strong correlation between determining judgment and  theoretical reason and an implied relationship between teleological and practical reason, I think Kant could have structured those connections better without sacrificing the determinative–reflective distinction you point out.

I might change my mind about that as I get deeper into the book.  I'm also not sure if the trifold structure I'm suggesting would amount to a logical division or merely  a different stylistic structure of the book.
